# Encrypt Telegram chat history

Tags: encryption, telegram-bot

I am currently trying to build a telegram bot for connecting emails with a telegram group.

The users should be able to write several messages and (whenever they wish) send the command `/sendEmail` to send all previously sent messages per email. (Example chat as in the picture below)

[image: Image showing bot sending an encryption code first, then user sending several messages and at last sending /sendEmail {ENCRYPTION_CODE}]

As Telegram provides no way to get the chat history, I need to store every single message the moment it is written. But as I don't want any developer to be able to read them, I'd like to encrypt them in a way they can only be decrypted upon sending the email.

Possible data one could use as encryption key:

- Encryption code sent by the bot/user (only sent rarely, not every message for the convenience of the user. Like in the picture)

Does anyone know of a way to encrypt all messages until the user sends `sendEmail`?

Comment: Don't take it personally, but storing chat messages outside of the app seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I would only store them until the email is sent and notify the user if he seems not to use this service anymore (so they can remove the bot). Also I ask the user for permission to store the messages and inform them about potential risks. If I also manage to encrypt them in an appropriate manner I believe this should be fine. Though if there is another way to do this, I would be happy to learn about it!